# MVVMLight C# how to change a button content

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm new to WPF with MVVMLight and struggling to grasp how things work.
I have a button in xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="29,374,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" 
    Command="{Binding BeginCollectionCommand}"/>
```

And have the View Model respond to the button press.
`BeginCollectionCommand = new RelayCommand(BeginCollectionCommandExecute, () => true);`

I failed to find the answer to my question on

- How to set the button to disable
- How to set the "content=" to "working..."
- How to re-enable the button when the project is complete
- How to set the "content=" to "Done"
- I also want to wait 5 seconds to set the content to "Start" again. I believe i can do this with a thread.sleep(5000) but the other parts I'm not clear on.

The View Model code has the button binding "BeginCollectionCommand" defined as

```
public RelayCommand BeginCollectionCommand { get; set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
  {
    BeginCollectionCommand = new RelayCommand(BeginCollectionCommandExecute, () => true);
    //at this point i believe is where i set the button content to "working..."
    //and disable.
  }

  public void BeginCollectionCommandExecute()
  {
    /// do my working class code

    //I think at this point I want to set the code to change button content to
    //enable, conent to "done" then wait and set to "start"
  }
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You questions could be sum up to three kinds of question.

1. How to enable or disable a button.
2. How to change content of a button.
3. How to change content after a period of time.

For first and second question, bind your button `IsEnable` to a property in viewModel and bind content to a string

In xaml.

```
<Button x:Name="button" 
    Content="{Binding ButtonString}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="29,374,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
    IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonEnabled}"
    Command="{Binding BeginCollectionCommand}"/>
```

In view model

```
    // Set true or button cannot be pressed.
    bool m_Enabled = true;
    public bool ButtonEnabled
    {
        get{  return m_Enalbed; }
        set{ m_Enabled = value; 
         // RaisePropertyChanged MUST fire the same case-sensitive name of property
             RaisePropertyChanged( "ButtonEnabled" );
           }
        }
    }

    public bool ButtonString
    {
     get;set;
    }
    bool m_String = false;
    public bool ButtonString
    {
        get{  return m_String; }
        set{ m_String = value; 
             // RaisePropertyChanged MUST fire the same case-sensitive name of property
             RaisePropertyChanged( "ButtonString" );
           }
        }
    }


public void BeginCollectionCommandExecute()
{
    //I simplify the way of variable passing, 
    //You need to take care of how to set property from command to viewmodel. 
    //A method delegate would be okay.
    ButtonEnabled = false;
    ButtonString = "Working";
    // working here
    ButtonEnabled = true;
    ButtonString = "Done";
}
```

For the third question, you may use a timer or a ThreadSleep is okay.

Comment: There are corrections to your sample code otherwise it was very very helpful. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: bool m_Enabled = true; //if not at true button is never available
        public bool ButtonEnabled
        {
            get { return m_Enabled; }
            set
            {
                m_Enabled = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("BtnEnabled");
            }
        }
        string m_String = "Start";
        public string ButtonString
        {
            get { return m_String; }
            set
            {
                m_String = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ButtonString");
            }
        }

Comment: I noticing that while running I'm not seeing the state changes of the button content change and the enable to disable. My working class runs for two minute so I know there is ample time for a change to occur. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean the state changes will take up to two minutes? Try to mock you operation by Thread.Sleep and check if it's working.

Comment: I come up with two possible reasons if it's not working. 1. `RaisePropertyChanged`'s argument is case sensitive.  2. Put `ButtonString` and `ButtonEnabled` in your viewmodel when you test it, do not put them in a nested property.

Comment: @auldh I found your "correction" comment has issue. You fired `RaisePropertyChanged("BtnEnabled")` instead of `RaisePropertyChanged("ButtonEnabled")`. Unless your Property name is BtnEnabled, or this property changed would not update `ButtonEnabled` properly.